# Google charts: error All series on a given axis must be of the same data type

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente codigo que es llevado por ajax a la función de google chart.

```
    $exgetChartDelitos =$conexion->Query("SELECT delito, COUNT(*)repes from geo_nsn group by delito having count(*)>1");
    $numeroFilas = mysql_num_rows($exgetChartDelitos);
    $datos[0] = array('Delito','Cantidad');



    for ($i=1; $i<($numeroFilas+1); $i++)
{
    $datos[$i] = array(mysql_result($exgetChartDelitos, $i-1, "delito"),
    (int) mysql_result($exgetChartDelitos, $i-1, "repes"));
}

   echo (json_encode($datos));
```

Sin embargo cuando quiero colocarle color a las barras (en este caso silver, pero mas adelante quiero que sea random) no me funciona y me sale el error:
Error:  All series on a given axis must be of the same data type

```
 $exgetChartDelitos =$conexion->Query("SELECT delito, COUNT(*)repes from geo_nsn group by delito having count(*)>1");
    $numeroFilas = mysql_num_rows($exgetChartDelitos);
    $datos[0] = array('Delito','Cantidad', '{ role: "style" }');



    for ($i=1; $i<($numeroFilas+1); $i++)
{
    $datos[$i] = array(mysql_result($exgetChartDelitos, $i-1, "delito"),
    (int) mysql_result($exgetChartDelitos, $i-1, "repes"), "silver" );
}

   echo (json_encode($datos));
```

Comment: Por favor actualiza tu pregunta con una muestra de la información que usarás en la gráfica. El error me indica que los **valores no son del mismo tipo de dato**.

Comment: los valores son strings para delitos y números para la cantidad, en el primer caso funciona correctamente, el problema es cuando agrego la opción: "{ role: "style}", a cada linea le agrego "silver" pero dice que no es del tipo que pide.

Comment: _Si te entendí bien_ le agregas el valor `style` a la columna **Cantidad**, pero ese valor no es un número. Intenta colocar un valor numérico y, _si estoy equivocado_, prueba con otros valores.

Comment: no , espera creo que no me expliqué bien, aunque me haz hecho caer en cuenta, si yo coloco '{ role: "style" }' antes de este debo colocar la descripción? , el código funcionaba con cantidad y descripción, sin embargo quería agregar un elemento más que es el color, en la documentación de google está asi:
 ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }],
   ['Copper', 8.94, '#b87333'],

Comment: Listo, encontré la solución, este rol style debería ser un array:
$datos[0] = array('Delito','Cantidad',array('role' => "style"));

Comment: @Mariano: No veo la razón para agregar [tag:google-visualization]. ¿Me explicas?

Comment: @Rubén Me estoy peleando con mi celular... No sé ni qué hice. Perdón por la confusión y gracias por avisar

Comment: Sólo quiero señalar que los métodos que usas para la base de datos son **obsoletos**, declarados tales porque son **vulnerables a [inyección SQL](http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php)**. No se recomienda usar más las extensiones `mysql_*`.

Comment: Me parece bien que animes a la gente a utilizar **mysqli**  o PDO pero es totalmente falso que sea por motivos de inyección. Véase la documentación: http://us2.php.net/manual/es/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Answer (score 1):

Solución:

```
$datos[0] = array('Delito','Cantidad',array('role' => "style"));
```

ref= https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41594553/all-series-on-a-given-axis-must-be-of-the-same-data-type-google-charts/41600330#41600330